# How to create Azure App Service from Web API?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management

I am creating a .Net Core(v3.1) web application that I have to create a new .Net Core(v3.1) app service from the Azure Management API. I am able to check availability but when I try to find that I am not able to find that but I am able to create App Service Plan but not able to create an app service.

Link to Create App Service Plan: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/appserviceplans/createorupdate)

Link for Rest API Documentation: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/)

**Code to Generate Access Token**

```
var client = new RestClient("https://login.microsoftonline.com/<SubscriptionID>/oauth2/token");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
request.AddParameter("client_id", "<ClientID>");
request.AddParameter("client_secret", "<ClientSecret>");
request.AddParameter("resource", "https://management.azure.com/");
IRestResponse Iresponse = client.Execute(request);
Token token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(Iresponse.Content);
```

**Code To Check Availablity**

```
using (var Httpclient = new HttpClient())
{
    Httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token.access_token);
    var baseUrl = new Uri($"https://management.azure.com/");
    var requestURl = baseUrl + @"/subscriptions/<SubscriptionID>/providers/Microsoft.Web/checknameavailability?api-version=2019-08-01";
    string body = "{\"name\":\"AvaiableCheck\",\"type\":\"slot\"}";
    var stringContent = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = Httpclient.PostAsync(requestURl, stringContent).Result;
    var a = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

If I get available in response I have to create a new app service in Azure App Service.

I am calling the below API of the PUT call.

```
var requestURl = baseUrl + @"/subscriptions/<SubscriptionGUID>/resourceGroups/<ResourceGroupName>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<SiteName>?api-version=2021-04-01";
```

In Response I get the below error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "MismatchingResourceName",
    "message": "The provided resource name 'TestAPIFromResource' did not match the name in the Url '<ResourceName>'."
  }
}
```

If anyone has an idea about that please let me know it helps me a lot.

Comment: Have you referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/createorupdate?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "not able".

Comment: @TomW I am not able to create a new App Service Under a particular Resource Group.

Comment: @JimXu Yes I have referred that but I have to create a new App Service, not a WebApp.

Comment: @DeepSoni what is stopping you? You need to provide sufficient information for people to help you.

Comment: @DeepSoni  Azure App Service is an HTTP-based service for hosting web applications, REST APIs, and mobile back ends. So if we want to create app service, we just need to create web API or mobile application: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview

Comment: Thanks For Response. @TomW I have to create App Service from my Web application(from C#).

Comment: @JimXu I have to create an app service from C# based web application in that user can select a location and enter the name of the app service.

Comment: @DeepSoni ok, so what is stopping you from doing that?

Comment: @TomW When I fire API
PUT: https://resources.azure.com/subscriptions/<SubscriptionID>/resourceGroups/<ResourceName>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites

I am getting below error:

{
  "error": {
    "code": "MismatchingResourceName",
    "message": "The provided resource name 'TestAPIFromResource' did not match the name in the Url '<ResourceName>'."
  }
}

Comment: @DeepSoni could you please add that information to the question?

Comment: The error message implies that you haven't replaced the example text `<ResourceName>` with the actual name of the resource to create.

Comment: @DeepSoni Could you please tell me what  you mean  app service?

Comment: @JimXu I have added details in the question you can check now. Also mention in which API I got an error.
It helps us a  lot to figure out the issue.